# How do you execute doPostBack from ASP.net in Python?

Tags: javascript, python, asp.net

This is a problem I have been wrestling with for days now.  I am trying to automate the download of files from [this](https://structuredginniemaes.ginnienet.com/Download/) website, and hopefully other websites with a similar construction.  I know the website is ASP and I know that all the download links call a doPostBack function, which has the form:

```
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
  if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
  theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
  theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
  theForm.submit();
  }
}
```

I have tried just clicking the links via selenium and phantomjs, which fails.  I then decided to try and emulate the function call.  I used mechanize for this, and did the following:

```
def python_func(self,url,target,argument):
  br = mechanize.Browser()
  br.set_handle_robots(False)
  br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; 
  rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.    0.1')]
  br.open(url)
  form_num = 0
  while True:
    try:
       inner_browser.select_form(nr=form_num)
    except FormNotFoundError:
         return False
    br.form.set_all_readonly(False)
    inner_browser["__EVENTTARGET"] = targ
    inner_browser["__EVENTARGUMENT"] = arg
    response = inner_browser.submit()
```

Unfortunately, the form does not seem to have a submit control and I get nothing from the submit call.  I have also tried emulating the post request by manually encoding the four fields ASP doPostBack has.  Those are eventtarget, eventargument, viewstate (has a default value), and eventvalidaiton (also has a default).  This does not work either - I end up getting the Ginnie Mae website all over again.

I am assuming that I can somehow take the doPostBack function and run it directly using a JavaScript interpreter, but I just do not know how to do that.  So far, I have mechanize, selenium, and phantomJS working for me, but I'm not sure if I can leverage any of that in order to run the code and get the file to download.